# E0144 a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, declaration, string-literals

I'm trying to solve this issue
E0144 a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

It does compile on different compilers but it gives me errors on visual studio 2019 it doesn't compile

Errors
C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'char *'
E0144       a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

I tried solving the issue but can't seem to understand it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;

int processString(char* string) {
    int vowels = 0;
    bool a = false, e = false, i = false, o = false, u = false;


    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(string); k++) {
        switch (string[k]) {
        case 'a':case 'A': a = true; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': e = true; break;
        case 'i':case 'I': i = true; break;
        case 'o':case 'O': o = true; break;
        case 'p':case 'U': u = true; break;
        }
    }
    vowels += a ? 1 : 0;
    vowels += e ? 1 : 0;
    vowels += i ? 1 : 0;
    vowels += o ? 1 : 0;
    vowels += u ? 1 : 0;


    return vowels; // the number of vowels in string
}

int main() {

    char* sports[] = { "football","basketball","golf","cricket","Chess","badminton" };
    int vowels;
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

        vowels = processString(sports[j]);
        cout << "String \'" << sports[j] << "\' contains \'" << vowels << "\' vowels.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you marked the line on which the error occurs. Otherwise, people must guess on which line the error is occuring or must attempt to compile the program themselves, in order to test in which line the error occurs.

Comment: In C++, for strings, use `std::string`.

Comment: "football" is const char* in C++ (unlike C), so assigning it to a char* array element is fishy.  Simply make it const char* sports[], and const char* parameter for processString().  Fwiw, there is a compiler setting that is available to make it work for old code that did not get it right.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > "Conformance mode" = No.  But get it right first.

Comment: *It does compile on different compilers* five bucks says that the other compilers were either used by ice-age mammoth hunters or [are reducing the hard error to a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/9brsxW6eo) that you subsequently ignored. Don't ignore warnings as they are the first line of defense against logic problems in the code.

Comment: Note that questions are generally of higher quality if they provide a [mre] of the problem. Most of your posted code is not required in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The real beauty of the [mre] (MRE) is it's hard to make one without finding and fixing the bug yourself. Usually you get a few passes in and the reduction in the code around the error allows you to see the error. Make the MRE early in the debugging process and you'll find you're done.

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < strlen(string)` -- You are calling `strlen` on each iteration of the loop.  That is a needless bottleneck.  Instead, compute `strlen(string)`, save it to a variable, and use the variable in the `for` loop expression.

Comment: @HansPassant "*`"football"` is `const char*` in C++ (unlike C)*" - incorrect, on both counts. It is a `const char[9]` in both languages, which *decays* into a `const char*` in certain contexts. It is just that C allows a string literal to be assigned to a non-const  `char*`, whereas C++ doesn't anymore since C++11.

Comment: You have an immutable string (or rather, char array). You want to assign its address to a pointer to mutable `char`. That's just not going to fly. Do you think that you could then use that pointer to modify the unmodifiable data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
char* sports[] = { "football","basketball","golf","cricket","Chess","badminton" };
```

is valid in C, but not in C++. In C++, pointers to [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) must be of type `const char *`.

Therefore, you should change the line to the following:

```
const char* sports[] = { "football","basketball","golf","cricket","Chess","badminton" };
```

If you want to pass a pointer to a string literal to the function `processString`, then you should also change the parameter of that function from `char *` to `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `strdup()` (or simply `std::string`). As the compiler suggests, `"football"` et. al. are `const char*` and a `const` cannot be used to initialize a non-const.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (5.13.5 String literals)

> 8 Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
> to as narrow string literals. **A narrow string literal has type
> “array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as
> defined below, and has static storage duration (6.7)

So you have to write

```
const char* sports[] = { "football","basketball","golf","cricket","Chess","badminton" };
```

This for loop uses a magic number 6.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

    vowels = processString(sports[j]);
    cout << "String \'" << sports[j] << "\' contains \'" << vowels << "\' vowels.\n";
}
```

Using magic numbers is error prone. Instead you could use a range-based for loop like

```
for ( const auto &s : sports ) {

    size_t vowels = processString( s );
    cout << "String \'" << s << "\' contains " << vowels << " vowels.\n";
}
```

The parameter of the function `processString` correspondingly must also have the qualifier `const` .

Moreover the function contains a bug because the boolean values are not reset to false within the for loop.

Using your approach the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t processString( const char* s ) {
    size_t vowels = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s ) {
        bool a = false, e = false, i = false, o = false, u = false;

        switch ( *s ) {
        case 'a':case 'A': a = true; break;
        case 'e':case 'E': e = true; break;
        case 'i':case 'I': i = true; break;
        case 'o':case 'O': o = true; break;
        case 'p':case 'U': u = true; break;
        }

        vowels += a ? 1 : 0;
        vowels += e ? 1 : 0;
        vowels += i ? 1 : 0;
        vowels += o ? 1 : 0;
        vowels += u ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return vowels; // the number of vowels in string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation, that made a perfect sense.